# Newly created S3 directory has 1969-12-31 as timestamp

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

I'm running into this wierd issue where all the directories I created on S3N have the same timestamp which is 1969-12-31

I created the directories using "hadoop fs -mkdir" and using mapreduce job and got the same timestamp.

How can I get the correct time stamp?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a hack built into the s3-hdfs implementation because s3 doesn't really have a notion of directories, so hadoop has nowhere to read directory creation / modification date from.

In fact in s3 all files are stored as root-level objects and a slash '/' is allowed in the key. So unlike hdfs, there is no metadata for a key prefix (directory).

Example, in hdfs:

`/some/path.txt` <- both /some and /some/path.txt have metadata containing created/modified dates

in S3:

`/some/path.txt` is the name of the file. There is no directory. Adding a slash as a separator is just convention that allows hadoop to pretend s3 has directories. You could call it some-path.txt if you liked (although hadoop wouldn't be as happy)

So when you run something like `hadoop fs -ls s3n://bucket/directory1/` it just has to use a default for the created date.